# How to get SourceMaps to load using Rails and Webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, source-maps, webpacker

I am running Rails 6.1.3 with webpacker 6.0.0.beta.6

When I run `rails webpacker:compile`, I can see the `.js` files as well as `.map` files emitted to `public/packs/js`.

The last line of one of the `.js` files says
`//# sourceMappingURL=application-b3a380c16a7bf12276e7.js.map` and that map file is indeed in the `public/packs/js` directory.

However, when I load `localhost:3000/foo/bar` into the browser, I get the message in the console

`DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/foo/application-b3a380c16a7bf12276e7.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`.

What do I need to do to have devtools request the correct location, which is: `http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-e0c3882abd2e74c48a38.js.map`?